# Ordenar values en un Treeview

Tags: python, json, tkinter, tree

estoy en una APP, que al cargar los datos desde un archivo JSON, y mostrarlos en un TREEVIEW, me salen los valores desordenados, he intentado ordenar los valores del diccionario antes y luego añadirlo al treeview pero no consigo ordenarlos, me pueden ayudar por favor.

Esta es la función que utilizo y que funciona para cargar los datos al treeview

```
def cargar_ventanas(self):

    #crear una lista vacia
    self.ventanas = []

    #limpiando el arbol de vistas
    self.limpiar_tree()

    #Cargar datos desde el archivo JSON
    with open('directory.json') as g:
            data = json.load(g)
            count = 0
            for md in data['INFRA']:
                
                #guardar solo el valor de 'object a una lista'
                self.ventanas.append(md['object'])
                if count % 2 == 0:
                    self.tree.insert(parent='', index='end', iid=count, text='', value=(md['object'],md['owner'],md['tipo'],md['ownerGroup'],md['code']), tags=('evenrow'))
                else:
                    self.tree.insert(parent='', index='end', iid=count, text='', value=(md['object'],md['owner'],md['tipo'],md['ownerGroup'],md['code']), tags=('oddrow'))
                count += 1
```

la estructura del archivo JSON es asi:

```
{
"EUROFRED": [
    {
      "object": "/BDistribuido/",
      "owner": "root",
      "tipo": "/F/",
      "ownerGroup": "Sistemas",
      "user": [
        "GEMMA ESCAR APARICIO", 
        "NINELA ELENA PAVEL MANCIU", 
        "RAMON RUIZ GARCIA"
      ],
      "code": "1-OK",
      "servers": [
        "ALL Servers"
      ],
      "risk": "",
      "impact": "",
      "variable": [
        "directory=\"/BDistribuido/\""
      ],
      "SO": "Linux"
    },
    {
      "object": "/BDistribuidoBatchDESA/",
      "owner": "root",
      "tipo": "/F/",
      "ownerGroup": "Sistemas",
      "user": [
        "GEMMA ESCAR APARICIO", 
        "NINELA ELENA PAVEL MANCIU", 
        "RAMON RUIZ GARCIA"
      ],
      "code": "1-OK",
      "servers": [
        "ALL Servers"
      ],
      "risk": "",
      "impact": "",
      "variable": [
        "directory=\"/BDistribuidoBatchDESA/\""
      ],
      "SO": "Linux"
    }
  ],
  "INFRA": [
    {
      "object": "/home/ess01012/RHEL/",
      "owner": "ess01012",
      "tipo": "/E/",
      "ownerGroup": "PHC",
      "user": [
        "Barbeito Zaldua, Idoia"
      ],
      "code": "1-OK",
      "servers": [
        "ALL Servers"
      ],
      "risk": "",
      "impact": "",
      "variable": [
        "directory=\"/home/ess01012/RHEL/\""
      ],
      "SO": "Linux"
    },
    {
      "object": "/tmp/javasharedresources/",
      "owner": "was",
      "tipo": "/S/",
      "ownerGroup": "EBH",
      "user": [
        "Silvia Pereira",
        "Alfonso Marcos Tarancon",
        "Almudena Outeda Rodríguez"
      ],
      "code": "1-OK",
      "servers": [
        "ALL Servers"
      ],
      "risk": "",
      "impact": "",
      "variable": [
        "directory=\"/tmp/javasharedresources/\""
      ],
      "SO": "Linux"
    },
    {
      "object": "/opt/SANnav/docker/docker/overlay2/19a827f987ca128698961358eb5b722794e55be4a515be5aabecb33cda1553e6/diff/usr/bin/docker",
      "owner": "root",
      "tipo": "/F/",
      "ownerGroup": "SANnav",
      "user": [
        "SANnav"
      ],
      "code": "1-OK",
      "servers": [
        "ALL server"
      ],
      "risk": "directorio : /opt/SANnav/ : (parte de un sofware de monitorización de la red de almancenamiento llamado SANnav)",
      "impact": "",
      "variable": [
        "fichero=\"/opt/SANnav/docker/docker/overlay2/19a827f987ca128698961358eb5b722794e55be4a515be5aabecb33cda1553e6/diff/usr/bin/docker\""
      ],
      "SO": "Aix"
    },
    {
      "object": "/opt/SANnav/docker/",
      "owner": "root",
      "tipo": "/F/",
      "ownerGroup": "SANnav",
      "user": [
        "Francisco Javier Bravo Diaz"
      ],
      "code": "1-OK",
      "servers": [
        "ALL server"
      ],
      "risk": "directorio : /opt/SANnav/ : (parte de un sofware de monitorización de la red de almancenamiento llamado SANnav)",
      "impact": "",
      "variable": [
        "directory=\"/opt/SANnav/docker/\""
      ],
      "SO": "Aix"
    },
    {
      "object": "/opt/SANnav/lost+found/",
      "owner": "root",
      "tipo": "/F/",
      "ownerGroup": "SANnav",
      "user": [
        "Francisco Javier Bravo Diaz"
      ],
      "code": "1-OK",
      "servers": [
        "ALL server"
      ],
      "risk": "directorio : /opt/SANnav/ : (parte de un sofware de monitorización de la red de almancenamiento llamado SANnav)",
      "impact": "",
      "variable": [
        "directory=\"/opt/SANnav/lost+found\""
      ],
      "SO": "Aix"
    }
  ]
}
```

**OS DEJO UN EJEMPLO EJECUTABLE**

```
import tkinter as tk
import json
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

class Ventana():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.title("CONTINOUS COMPLIANCE")
        self.root.geometry("870x300")
        self.widgets_ventanas()
    
    def widgets_ventanas(self):

        # creamos boton mostrar listas
        self.btnBuscar = ttk.Button(
            self.root,
            text='Mostrar',
            command=self.cargar_ventanas
        )
        self.btnBuscar.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)

        ## --- creamos el scrollbar
        self.tree_scrollbar=tk.Scrollbar(self.root, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
        self.tree_scrollbar.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=N+S,padx=(0,5), pady=10)
        
        ## ---creamos el treeview
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(
            self.root, 
            yscrollcommand=self.tree_scrollbar.set,
            height=10,
        )
        ## ---configuramos el scroll al trieview
        self.tree_scrollbar.config(command=self.tree.yview)
        ## ---creamos las columnas
        self.tree['columns'] = ("NAME","OWNER","TIPO","OWNERGROUP","CODE")
        ## --- formato a las columnas
        self.tree.column("#0", width=0, stretch=NO)
        self.tree.column("NAME", anchor=W, width=350)
        self.tree.column("OWNER", anchor=CENTER, width=150)
        self.tree.column("TIPO", anchor=CENTER, width=100)
        self.tree.column("OWNERGROUP", anchor=CENTER, width=150)
        self.tree.column("CODE", anchor=CENTER, width=100)
        ## --- indicar cabecera
        self.tree.heading("#0", text="", anchor=W)
        self.tree.heading("#1", text="NAME", anchor=W)
        self.tree.heading("#2", text="OWNER", anchor=CENTER)
        self.tree.heading("#3", text="TIPO", anchor=CENTER)
        self.tree.heading("#4", text="OWNER GROUP", anchor=CENTER)
        self.tree.heading("#5", text="CODE", anchor=CENTER)
        self.tree.tag_configure('oddrow', background="#CEE5D0", font=('Verdana', 14))
        self.tree.tag_configure('evenrow', background="#F3F0D7", font=('Verdana', 14))
        
        self.tree.grid(column=0, row=1, pady=10, padx=(5,0), sticky=E+W)

    def limpiar_tree(self):
        records = self.tree.get_children()
        for elemnt in records:
            self.tree.delete(elemnt)
    
    def cargar_ventanas(self):

        #limpiando el arbol de vistas
        self.limpiar_tree()

        #Cargar datos desde el archivo JSON
        with open('directory.json') as g:
                data = json.load(g)
                count = 0
                #aqui eleginos el cliente que queremos
                for md in data['INFRA']:
                    
                    #guardar solo el valor de 'object a una lista'
                    if count % 2 == 0:
                        self.tree.insert(parent='', index='end', iid=count, text='', value=(md['object'],md['owner'],md['tipo'],md['ownerGroup'],md['code']), tags=('evenrow'))
                    else:
                        self.tree.insert(parent='', index='end', iid=count, text='', value=(md['object'],md['owner'],md['tipo'],md['ownerGroup'],md['code']), tags=('oddrow'))
                    count += 1

    def mainloop(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Ventana()
    app.mainloop()
```

Lo que me gustaria es que la columna 'NAME', del treeview salga ordenada, no si es posible o como podria consegirlo. gracias.

os dejo una imagen

[image: quiero la columan name me salga en orden]

Comment: Por naturaleza un diccionario no está ordenado, solo almacena el hash del valor por así decirlo y esa es su ventaja en velocidad con respecto a una lista o una tupla. [OrderedDict()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) Quizás esto es lo que buscas

Comment: @JoseRodriguez [Según la documentación](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects), por encima de la versión 3.7 de Python, los diccionarios garantizan el orden de inserción. Por lo que es probable que el OP esté usando una versión de Python inferior.

Comment: Siempre aprendes algo nuevo y me pasa por no mirar bien :) Gracias. Al menos si tiene que usar una version anterior por necesidad ya sabe por donde empezar.

Comment: Si uso la version 3.6.8, porque es la que me funciona, al cambiar de version en el VS code me da error en librerias, he probado lo de la documentacion que me envias y no me ordenada

Comment: sortedDic = collections.OrderedDict(
                        sorted(dic_vtn.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]))
                    sortedDict = sorted(
                        dic_vtn.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(0))
                    print(sortedDic)
                    print("DICT : ", sortedDict)

Comment: He probado con operator que he visto en documentacion o OrderedDict y tampoco ordenada, no muestra error me muestra la salida pero no ordenada.

Comment: @JoseRodriguez es un placer c:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por supuesto que es posible ingresarlo ordenado en el treeview!

Lo que tienes que ordenar NO es un diccionario, si no una lista. Para eso no necesitas versiones superiores de Python ni un OrderedDict. Python en sí ya ofrece una función para ordenar listas.

El siguiente código es una muestra creada a partir del código ofrecido en la pregunta:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

import json

# Cargo el json
with open("datos.txt") as f:
    datos = json.load(f)

# creo el treeview
tree = ttk.Treeview()
tree['columns'] = ("NAME","OWNER","TIPO","OWNERGROUP","CODE")
## --- formato a las columnas
tree.column("#0", width=0, stretch=NO)
tree.column("NAME", anchor=W, width=350)
tree.column("OWNER", anchor=CENTER, width=150)
tree.column("TIPO", anchor=CENTER, width=100)
tree.column("OWNERGROUP", anchor=CENTER, width=150)
tree.column("CODE", anchor=CENTER, width=100)
## --- indicar cabecera
tree.heading("#0", text="", anchor=W)
tree.heading("#1", text="NAME", anchor=W)
tree.heading("#2", text="OWNER", anchor=CENTER)
tree.heading("#3", text="TIPO", anchor=CENTER)
tree.heading("#4", text="OWNER GROUP", anchor=CENTER)
tree.heading("#5", text="CODE", anchor=CENTER)

tree.pack()

# agrego los valores ordenados
for md in sorted(datos['INFRA'], key=lambda md:md['object']):
    tree.insert("", "end", value=(md['object'],md['owner'],md['tipo'],md['ownerGroup'],md['code']))
```

Pero la linea importante y que me dedicaré a explicar es esta:

```
sorted(datos['INFRA'], key=lambda md:md['object'])
```

Usamos la función [sorted](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/sorted) de Python para ordenar la lista datos["INFRA"]. El argumento opcional key acepta una función que transforma cada item de la lista y ordena según la versión transformada.
El contenido de la columna NAME siempre va a ser md['object'] donde md es un item de la lista. Por lo que lo ordenaremos por dicho valor.

Este es el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se que no te ofrecí directamente tu código original modificado, pero estoy seguro de que lograrás implementar mi idea en tu código por ti mismo.

Comment: Funciona perfecto, muchísimas Gracias @Dante,

Comment: De nada, es un placer ayudar c: